# Layer just for annotations

Tags: qgis, layers, annotation

Im relatively new to QGIS and would like to know whether or not I can save my form annotations to a layer so I can turn them on or off.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Something you may not have picked up from the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) is that we try to stick straight to the question and dispense with things like thanks and signatures so please do not be offended when I remove these from your question in a moment.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to save your annotations as a layer. Simply toggle the *Text Annotation* function in the toolbar and press **Ctrl + T** to switch it on/off. Your annotations will be saved within your project.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can store your annotations in a point layer and label it by `[Right click >> Properties]`. Follow the simple steps below:

- Make sure your point feature is not visible. only the label is
  visible. `Right click on layer` >>`properties`>> `Style` tab. Select
  `Simple marker` or simple choose any `hollow marker` and set `Size` to `0.00000` as shown in below snap.
  Click Ok to save the settings.

[image]

- Now again `Right click on layer` >>`properties`>> `Label`. Change
  the size and type of font and other parameters according to your
  choice. Click ok to apply if everything is looking good. Again, go to same tab to save the style for future use. Good luck.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS >= 3.22 there is the possibility to create an annotation layer. You need to activate `Annotations Toolbar`  in `View\Toolbars`. You will see something like this:

[image]

Use the first button for creating the layer then add the polygons or the text. You can add a general description of the layer in the layer property.

More informations here:
https://north-road.com/2021/10/21/introducing-annotation-layers-in-qgis-3-22/